# C# application to connect to a mobile application using bluetooth

Tags: c#, mobile, bluetooth, mobile-phones

I`m asking this question again as I got no answer for about a week now ...

I want to know how to write a C# desktop application that can connect to the mobile version of the same application (that I will create). The desktop application will be used as a backup/restore for the mobile application.

I want to know also how to write the mobile version (using C# if possible).

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# application to connect to a mobile application using bluetooth](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684841/c-application-to-connect-to-a-mobile-application-using-bluetooth)

Comment: "asking this question again as I got no answer for about a week now" - that's a low, even for you. :)

Comment: You do not provide enough information to answer your question. Which desktop OS are you writing for? Which phone hardware? Why do you want to use Bluetooth for backup/restore? ActiveSync was designed for this, why can you not use it?

Comment: @Dour High Arch: I`m working on Windows 7 (64-bit). My Mobile is Nokia 7610. I`m not looking for a phone backup. I want to write an application that can uses a database (on the phone can use xml or any kind of dbs that work on nokia cell phones) and a desktop application that can connect (using the bluetooth) to the application and copy (backup/restore) the database of the application.

Answer (score -1):

May i know, in what way you want to communicate with the mobile version of the application? Ideally the cross domain/application communication is possible using services(WCF/Webservices).

I hope the following link may be useful for you : [Bluetooth in C#, Which stack, Which SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057220/bluetooth-in-c-which-stack-which-sdk)